# Nextjs how to not unmount previous page when going to next page (to keep state)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

we are using Nextjs in our web app.
We want to keep stack of pages where users visit to keep state of component on back navigation.
How should we do that?
I have tried https://github.com/exogen/next-modal-pages, but it calls getInitialProps of previous pages again on back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my solution with a custom _app.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, memo } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const ROUTES_TO_RETAIN = ['/dashboard', '/top', '/recent', 'my-posts']

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const retainedComponents = useRef({})

  const isRetainableRoute = ROUTES_TO_RETAIN.includes(router.asPath)

  // Add Component to retainedComponents if we haven't got it already
  if (isRetainableRoute && !retainedComponents.current[router.asPath]) {
    const MemoComponent = memo(Component)
    retainedComponents.current[router.asPath] = {
      component: <MemoComponent {...pageProps} />,
      scrollPos: 0
    }
  }

  // Save the scroll position of current page before leaving
  const handleRouteChangeStart = url => {
    if (isRetainableRoute) {
      retainedComponents.current[router.asPath].scrollPos = window.scrollY
    }
  }

  // Save scroll position - requires an up-to-date router.asPath
  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChangeStart)
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChangeStart)
    }
  }, [router.asPath])

  // Scroll to the saved position when we load a retained component
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRetainableRoute) {
      window.scrollTo(0, retainedComponents.current[router.asPath].scrollPos)
    }
  }, [Component, pageProps])

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: isRetainableRoute ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
        {Object.entries(retainedComponents.current).map(([path, c]) => (
          <div
            key={path}
            style={{ display: router.asPath === path ? 'block' : 'none' }}
          >
            {c.component}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {!isRetainableRoute && <Component {...pageProps} />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Gist - https://gist.github.com/GusRuss89/df05ea25310043fc38a5e2ba3cb0c016

Comment: we have found this library: https://github.com/CJY0208/react-activation

Comment: There is one problem with this approach though, if you navigate to a another page and make updates that affect the retained page, the retained page's data will be stale when you come back. And you can not utilize useEffect etc. to rerender the component with fresh data because the retained page does not get re-mount but it just continues its life-cycle where it left before. Thus, any solution to this problem would be awesome!

Comment: Found a solution! If you like to keep your page state before leaving but would like to get fresh data according to your state when you came back, you can use router object of next/router. All you need to do is use routeChangeComplete in router.events.on inside the useEffect. Pass router as dependency and whenever you switch back to the retained page your useEffect will be triggered and you can make necessary API calls or whatever inside the router.events.on's callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "save the state of the page by not un-mounting it" but you can save the state of your app in `_app.js` file, and the rebuild the previous page from it.

Check the [redux example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-redux) from `next`'s repo.